# DF Robot Electronic Solonid Lock Relay Pinout

Tags: relay, pinout, latching-relay

I'm trying to figure out what I'm looking at on this pinout diagram.  Specifically I'm looking at how the line voltage connects to the relay in this figure.

I'm pretty sure that NO stands for normally open, COM stands for common connection, but I don't know what NA stands for in this diagram?

[The lock can be found on their website here](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1856.html?search=Electric%20Solenoid%20Lock&description=true)

[image: Relay Pinout]

[image: Full Schematic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As is shown in this photo of the underside of the DFRobot relay module the third terminal is not connected to anything.

In your case it is just used to connect the two black wires together.

So in your circuit the tred wire is switched by the relay contacts and the black wire is connected directly to the lock.

Comment: Thank you!!!    :)

Comment: I found that photo on the DFRobot web site.